# Akka Streams: handling Future inside GraphStage Source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to build an Akka Stream **Source** which receives data by making `Future` API calls (*The nature of API is scrolling, which incrementally fetches results*). To build such **Source**, I am using [GraphStage](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html#custom-processing-with-graphstage).

I have modified the [NumberSource example](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/v2.6.14/akka-docs/src/test/scala/docs/stream/GraphStageDocSpec.scala#L41-L68) which simply pushes an `Int` at a time. The only change I did was to replace that `Int` with `getvalue(): Future[Int]` (*to simulate the API call*):

```
class NumbersSource extends GraphStage[SourceShape[Int]] {
  val out: Outlet[Int] = Outlet("NumbersSource")
  override val shape: SourceShape[Int] = SourceShape(out)

  // simple example of future API call
  private def getvalue(): Future[Int] = Future.successful(Random.nextInt())


  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
            // Future API call
            getvalue().onComplete{
              case Success(value) =>
                println("Pushing value received..") // this is currently being printed just once
                push(out, counter)
              case Failure(exception) =>
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
}

// Using the Source and Running the stream

  val sourceGraph: Graph[SourceShape[Int], NotUsed] = new NumbersSource
  val mySource: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)

  val done: Future[Done] = mySource.runForeach{
    num => println(s"Received: $num") // This is currently not printed
  }
  done.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

The above code doesn't work. The println statement inside `setHandler` is executed just once and nothing is pushed downstream.

How should such Future calls be handled ? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use [getAsyncCallback](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html#using-asynchronous-side-channels) by making changes as follow:

```
class NumbersSource(futureNum: Future[Int]) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[Int]] {
  val out: Outlet[Int] = Outlet("NumbersSource")
  override val shape: SourceShape[Int] = SourceShape(out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

      override def preStart(): Unit = {
        val callback = getAsyncCallback[Int] { (_) =>
          completeStage()
        }
        futureNum.foreach(callback.invoke)
      }

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          val value: Int = ??? // How to get this value ??
          push(out, value)
        }
      })
    }
}

// Using the Source and Running the Stream

def random(): Future[Int] = Future.successful(Random.nextInt())

  val sourceGraph: Graph[SourceShape[Int], NotUsed] = new NumbersSource(random())
val mySource: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)

  val done: Future[Done] = mySource.runForeach{
    num => println(s"Received: $num") // This is currently not printed
  }
  done.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

But, now I am stuck at how to grab the value computed from Future. In case of a `GraphStage`, `Flow`, I could use:

```
val value = grab(in) // where in is Inlet of a Flow
```

But, what I have is a `GraphStage`, `Source`, so I have no idea how to grab the Int value of computed Future above.

Comment: Try to change the source as lazySource to see what happens. Do you need to create a GraphStageLogic?. I think that you could create a Source from a Future: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/future.html and use statefulMapConcat for the counter.

Comment: I tried as: `lazy val mySource: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph)`. But got same results, so didn't work. Yes, I need `GraphStageLogic ` because the Future API call is a scrolling API. It requires passing the scroller state from one response to another, to incrementally fetch results. Also, I need to have some buffering and error handling. From my understanding, it can't be built using Source from a Future. It could be achieved using `Source.actorPublisher`, but that's now deprecated and docs is suggest to use `GraphStage`, which is what I am trying.

Comment: Why is this question being voted as Close ?? All I am asking is how to use `Future` inside `GraphStage[SourceShape[T]]`. If it's not possible to use, then that should be explicitly suggested.

Comment: If the downstream has not pulled already when the future completes and the async callback gets the value (you are ignoring the value now with the `(_)`) you'll have to hang on to the value in a field until there is a pull.

Note that as others have also said, there already are a few operators for interacting with futures though, so unless this is just a learning exercise I'd recommend using one of them (`mapAsync`, `Source.future`, `unfoldAsync` etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you are trying to implement an infinite source out of elements computed in `Future`s then there is really no need to do it with your own `GraphStage`. You can do it simply as below:

```
Source.repeat(())
    .mapAsync(parallelism) { _ => Future.successful(Random.nextInt()) }
```

The `Source.repeat(())` is simply an infinite source of some arbitrary values (of type `Unit` in this case, but you can change `()` to whatever you want since it's ignored here). `mapAsync` then is used to integrate the asynchronous computations into the flow.

Comment: With this suggestion, are you suggesting that it's absolutely not possible to handle `Future` inside `GraphStage` ?

Comment: Not at all. It's perfectly possible to handle `Futures` and other asynchronous constructs inside the `GraphStage`. In fact operators like `.mapAsync` do exactly that (they are implemented as `GraphStages` under the hood). If you really want to make your own stage you can take a look at the implementation of e.g. `.mapAsync` in the akka source code, but you will see that implementing `GraphStage`s is non trivial and quite tricky. It's usually preferred to use the available operators (hence my answer) and only fall back to own implementation as a last resort.

Comment: Ah okay, understood. Thanks :) But, I think it will be very difficult to put the API call inside `.mapAsync`, for my use case. The API is a paginated one and requires scrolling through each page, which means state management, and also buffering. SO, I need control over the state of scroll, when the scroll finishes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would join to  the other answer to try to avoid creating your own graphstage. After some experimentation this is what seems to work for me:

```
type Data = Int

trait DbResponse {
  // this is just a callback for a compact solution
  def nextPage: Option[() => Future[DbResponse]] 
  def data: List[Data]
}

def createSource(dbCall: DbResponse): Source[Data, NotUsed] = {
  val thisPageSource = Source.apply(dbCall.data)
  val nextPageSource = dbCall.nextPage match {
    case Some(dbCallBack) => Source.lazySource(() => Source.future(dbCallBack()).flatMapConcat(createSource))
    case None             => Source.empty
  }
  thisPageSource.concat(nextPageSource)
}

val dataSource: Source[Data, NotUsed] = Source
   .future(???: Future[DbResponse]) // the first db call
   .flatMapConcat(createSource)
```

I tried it out and it works almost perfectly, I couldn't find out why, but the second page is instantaneously requested, but the rest will work as expected (with backpressure and what not).